# Looking to modify an index formula to check a second variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with the a column for Location and a column for channel. It's organized as follows:

Column A - Column B
LocationA - Channel 1 
LocationA - Channel 2 
LocationA - Channel 4 
LocationB - Channel 2 
LocationB - Channel 3

I'm trying to populate a second sheet thats organized as follows:

```
        Channel 1   Channel 2  Channel 3   Channel 4
```

LocationA

LocationB

LocationC

I'm trying to add text to each channel column if the Location contains that channel.

I've tried to use this formula:

=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))

But it doesnt confirm that the result matches the Channel column. If I manipulate the main data set and filter by Channel first, it works, but I'm hoping there is a way to avoid the front end work to make it  more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you data starting from A2 through B6

form D2 to D4 (Location1,Location2,Location3)

form E1 to I1 (Channel 1,Channel 2,Channel 3,Channel 4)

Try this Array Formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in E2

and drag down and to right

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($D2&E$1,$A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6,0)),"Ok","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your `INDEX+MATCH` formula, you want to return the **corresponding Channel Name** in the new table **for each matched Location and Channel Name**.

One way of doing that is to use **AGGREGATE** to find out the position of the Channel Name in the Channel Name range, and then use **INDEX** to return the actual name.

Presume you have **named** the following:

1. **Locations**: all location names in Column A, eg. `A1:A6`;
2. **Channels**: all channel names in Column B, eg. `B1:B6`.

Here it the formula presume your new table range is `D1:H4`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Channels,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(Channels)/(Locations=$D2)/(Channels=E$1),1)),"")
```

Drag it across board to apply to the rest.

[image: Solution]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)